# Java File mkdirs() returns true but does not create folder under load

Tags: file, mkdirs

I am facing issue with File.mkdirs().  I am creating few hundred folders in parallel, but seems like few times, this mkdir() api returns true but folder wasn't really created(java 1.8).  I have pasted my sample code below, any ideas?

My Sample code and output is here: https://pastebin.com/aYWDw6JZ
It creates folders most of the time but fails sometimes.

```
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    long randData = (long) (System.currentTimeMillis() + (Math.random() * 100000)); 
    String folderPath = File.separatorChar + "data" + File.separatorChar + "ext" + File.separatorChar + randData;
    File testFolder = new File(folderPath);
    if (!testFolder.exists()) {
        if(testFolder.mkdirs() == false)
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + ": folder creation failed!");

    }
    String filename = testFolder + File.separator + "test.txt";
    File testFile = new File(filename);
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    boolean bCreated = false;
    try {
        //Thread.sleep(1000);
        if(testFolder.exists() == false) {
            System.out.println("Folder not created!");
            System.out.println("Folder: " + testFolder.getAbsolutePath() + " does not exist!");
        }else
            bCreated = true;
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(testFile);
        fileOutputStream.close();
        testFile.delete();
        testFolder.delete();

        //System.out.println("success:" + testFile.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Folder created? " + testFolder + ": " + bCreated);
        //back off and see if the folder is really created
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Checking again, " + testFolder.getAbsolutePath() + " created? " + testFolder.exists());
    }

}
```

Output:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \data\ext\1521045935714\test.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at DiskFolderCreationThread.run(DiskFolderCreationThread.java:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Folder created? \data\ext\1521045935714: true
Checking again, C:\data\ext\1521045935714 created? false
```

Comment: I am seeing this EXACT same problem.  Seems like a bug related to multiple calls to mkdirs() in succession, but I haven't been able to confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to update my finding as a solution.  I found out that in my application, multiple threads are trying to create folder and if two threads are simultaneously trying to create folder with the same name, I see this mkdirs() behavior, otherwise its fine.  I eliminated this condition and make sure the folder names are unique across threads and no issues now.